# What happens if two python processes call the same function simultaneously?

Tags: python

Let's say, python process_1.py and process_2.py are both calling a function simultaneously. Both processes are running independently. None of the calls is threaded or protected by mutexes.

- The function reads a large text file (~2mb), and performs a few HTTP GET and POST jobs. Based on the HTTP get responses, it composes and outputs a large json file. The whole function takes around 1 min to complete.
- HTTP POST does not interfere with each other.
- HTTP GET jobs are unique to each process. So the JSON output will also be unique to each process. They would write to two different JSON output files.

In this generic case:

- Would these two processes somehow interfere with the expected execution of the function? In other words, would the data integrity of the function would remain intact?
- Would the execution of the function be different if only just one process calls this function?
- Could there be a race condition?

Comment: The two  processes will not impact each other in any way.  Each one runs in its own memory space.  They won't even know that the other exists.  What are you concerned about?

Comment: It sounds like it depends what the function does exactly. Could the POSTs interfere with each other? Could they write to the same JSON file? Overall, are you familiar with [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)?

Comment: Generically: something will happen.  Too much specific information is missing to be able to give a more specific answer.

Comment: It is exactly the same as if the two processes were running on two separate computers.  Processes are inherently protected from each other.  That is the purpose of an operating system.

Comment: The question becomes slightly more interesting if you're asking about two Python threads in the same process.  In that case, they ARE sharing the same memory space, and do have visibility to the same variables and objects.

Comment: @TimRoberts Interesting! So what happens if it is two python threads in the same process?

Comment: They all use the same global variables.  Local variables in functions are separate.  The "global interpreter lock" means only one thread at a time can be running Python code, but if you abuse globals, you can have conflicts.